# How to send the input text box value to angularjs onclick on the text box?

Tags: html, angularjs

Below is my html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in client">
     <td><input type =text id = "id" value = {{c.id}} onclick = "display();" > </input> </td>
     <td><input type =text value = {{c.fname}}></td>
</tr>
```

My js:

```
 function display()
 {
     var x=document.forms["form"]["id"].value;
     alert(x);       
 }
```

I am getting the input value in the alert box successfully but how to get this value in another angular js function. I tried the below code but not working please suggest me

```
<input type =text id = "id" value = {{c.id}} ng-model = user.id ng-click ="init(user)" > </input>
```

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have set up your application properly, you simply create the `init()` function in your controller

```
$scope.init = function (user) {
    // function implementation
};
```

Also make sure you format your HTML correctly

```
<input type="text" id="id" value="{{c.id}}" ng-model="user" ng-click ="init(user)" />
```

Comment: is it possible to give ng-click in input text box?

Comment: <input type ="text" value = "sample" ng-model = "user" ng-click ="init(user)" />  I gave it like this its showing empty text box, why I am not getting the sample in text box

Comment: `ng-model = "user"` overrides `value = "sample"`. You could set the value of `user` in HTML `<input type="text"  ng-model="user" ng-click="init(user)" ng-init="user='sample'" />` or in your controller. Also, depending on what you want to achieve, you may want to consider `ng-change` and `ng-focus`. A user could type into the text box without clicking.

Comment: thanks working for sample.one last doubt instead of sample I need to give a dynamic value from my collection object ie c.id (from this<tr ng-repeat="c in client">)

Comment: Make your `ng-model` the value you want there (i.e. `ng-model="c.id"`).

Answer (score -1):

A much more cleaner way to accomplish the same thing would be to just set the value on the click event for example.

```
<td onclick="user.id=ID"> </td>
```

Comment: I think you mixed up angularjs with java script?